# Evan's statement about integral of the divergence of a vector field.

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, divergence-theorem

At the start of Evan;s textbook there is this statement:
[image]

How can we conclude 3 from the first equality? Why can't it be that the divergence is positive and negative over the volume in equal proportions so that the integral is 0 iver the full domain, while being 0 in only a small subset of it? i.e. why is it necessarily true that the divergence is 0 over the full domain?

Comment: Can you quote the full text? WHat are $U$ and $V$? Surely he says something about one of the sets being arbitrary (eg if $V$ is an arbitrary open subset of $U$, then the implication does follow)?

Comment: I added the full paragraph and I think it does say what you are saying. Although I am still not 100% clear on why that implies the conclusionm.

Comment: This is a very good exercise to work out in detail. If $f:U\to\Bbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that for every open subset $V\subset U$, $\int_Vf\,dx=0$, then prove $f=0$ on $U$. Either try to work it out yourself, or look on MSE (there are definitely questions about it... but this is an elementary exercise if $f$ is assumed continuous, so try it yourself first). More general is if $f:U\to\Bbb{R}$ is locally Lebesgue integrable and for every open ball $V\subset U$, we have $\int_Vf\,dx=0$, then $f=0$ a.e on $U$ (there are other MSE questions which deal with this or slight variants).

Comment: The fact that we're allowing $V$ to be an arbitrary open subset of $U$ rules out your type of counterexample of positive and negative divergence cancelling each other' effects out.

Comment: Is it because since the statement holds for any smooth subregion then for any point you can define a convergent series for which this statement holds, emaning at that particular point,a t the limit, it mus tbe 0, and because this point was chosen arbitrarily it must be true for all points?

Comment: this has nothing to do with convergent series. We're only dealing with continuous functions. THink about your attempt at a counterexample (a good attempt). The idea you came up with was positive and negative parts cancelling themselves out. Ok, but that only works if you consider a large enough region where there are opposite signs. What if you focus on a much smaller region of space?

Comment: That's, i think, what I am trying to say. The statement holds for any parition of the domain, so I can keep making smaller and smaller partitions around any point and ti will always be true, meaning it must be true for any point, so it;s true for all points in the domain.

Comment: Right, so formally, one way of proving it (actually much stronger than what you need) is to show that if $f$ is continuous at a point $a$ then $f(a)=\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1}{\text{vol}(B_r)}\int_{B_r(a)}f(x)\,dx$, where $B_r$ is an open ball of radius $r$. So, if the integrals are zero, the limit is $0$, so $f(a)=0$, and since $a$ is arbitrary, $f=0$. An alternative proof outline: suppose for contradiction there is a point $a\in U$ where $f(a)\neq 0$; WLOG, assume $f(a)>0$. What does continuity imply? So, what can you say about $\int_{B_r(a)}f(x)\,dx$ if $r>0$ is very small?

Comment: I leave it to you to fill in these details and write it up formally :)

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_0 \in U$ is such that $div(F)(x_0) = h > 0$. Since $U$ is open and $div(F)$ is continuous, there is $r > 0$ such that $B(x_0, r) \subset U$ and $div(F)(x) > h/2$ for all $x \in V := B(x_0, r)$. Thus
$$\int_{V}div(F)(x)\,dx \geq \int_{V}h/2\,dx = h/2 \cdot m(V) > 0,$$
since $m(V) > 0$.